# Is $f$ uniformly continuous in $A \cup B$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be only closed in $\mathbb R$, and $f$ uniformly continuous function in $A$ and $B$, is $f$ still uniformly continuous on the union of these two sets?

It is not specified whether $A$ and $B$ are limited, so I could't say that are compact.

Answer (score 2):

I think you put your finger of the issue.  $A$ and $B$ don't have to be compact.

Let $$A= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[2n+1,2n+2-\frac1n\right]\\
B= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[2n,2n+1-\frac1n\right]
$$ and left $f$ be identically $0$ on $A$ and identically $1$ on $B$. There are points in $A$ and $B$ arbitrarily close to one another.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, it my answer, one of the sets wasn't closed; I missed that condition. (+1)

Comment: You could make it a little easier with $$A=\{2,4,6,8,\dots\}, B=\{2+1/2,4+1/4,6+1/6,8+1/8,\dots\}$$ and $f=0$ on $A,$ $f=1$ on $B.$